# Zoom 5.15 crashes on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, zoom-meeting

I have a strange behavior that I cannot solve myself.
I'm using Zoom on Ubuntu 22.04. On one machine (laptop) all works fine. On a Desktop zoom crashes when I start screen sharing.
In `/var/log/syslog` I find this entry:

```
Jul 26 10:03:22 detlef-MS-7C37 kernel: [   87.741894] zoom[6638]: segfault at 5631bc40e9a0 ip 00007f0b5ef9dc4d sp 00007ffc8528fb50 error 6 in nouveau_dri.so[7f0b5e6f5000+ff5000]
Jul 26 10:03:22 detlef-MS-7C37 kernel: [   87.741905] Code: 8d 67 20 55 53 48 8b 6f 28 48 8b 5d 08 49 39 ec 74 2d 0f 1f 00 48 8b 7d 18 ff 55 10 48 8b 55 00 48 8b 45 08 48 89 ef 48 89 dd <48> 89 42 08 48 89 10 e8 57 b9 75 ff 48 8b 5b 08 4c 39 e5 75 d6 5

The version of nouveau_dri.so is (dpkp -l *nouveau*)
ii  libdrm-nouveau2:amd64      2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64        Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau 1:1.0.17-2build1          amd64        X.Org
 X server -- Nouveau display driver
```

I updated zoom-client from snap (5.15.2) - no success..

-edited:
ldd shows

```
 ldd $(type -p zoom)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd0e3b2000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7d06b80000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7d065d6000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7d06a99000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7d06a79000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7d063ae000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7d06ba2000)
```

The crash report is huge.

I upgraded to 5.15.2 and when I start screen share a dialog opens where I should select what to share. This dialog is empty.
Therefore I believe that this might be the root problem.

I believe its an issue with wayland. I will investigate further towards that direction

Comment: Look at the `*zoom*` file in `/var/crash/`, it's a flat text file. Are you missing a shared library? `ldd $(type -p zoom)`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by installing a specific driver for my graphic card. Nouveau driver seems to be the problem for this.